# GWT UI not updating due to heavy processing in listBox's onChange event handler

Tags: gwt, event-handling, scheduler

I have a list Box, on whose onChange(), I am updating another listBox.
So the code is something like

```
ListBox l1 = new ListBox();
...some items added to l1..

ListBox l2 = new ListBox();
l2.setEnabled(false);

l1.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {               
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
         //Show info msg
         //Update label text on top of the page with "Loading.."

        //..Do some processing here..

        L2.setEnabled(true);
        L2.getElement().setInnerHTML(html);
    }
```

This is working all fine, except for one glitch. The UI is stuck and both l1, l2 and label don't reflect the change until the processing is done. l2 would ofcourse reflect at later point of time, but l1 and info aren't showing up either.

I tried using scheduledDeferred as --

```
l1.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {               
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
         //Show info msg
         //Update label text on top of the page with "Loading.."

         Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
             @Overide
             public void execute() {
                //..Do some processing here..
            }
        }

         L2.setEnabled(true);
         L2.getElement().setInnerHTML(html);
    }
}
```

But above is still not helping, it's still working as usual. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled command does exactly the same thing as the previous snippet - it performs some processing, *then* updates the UI. what you need to do is first update the UI, *then* perform the processing (hopefully the processing doesn't lock up the browser) .

try this:

```
l1.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {               
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
         //Show info msg
         //Update label text on top of the page with "Loading.."

         Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
             @Overide
             public void execute() {
                //..Do some processing here....
               performSomethingReallyExpensive();
            }
        }
        L2.setEnabled(true);
        //hopefully, this 'html' variable doesn't depend on performSomethingReallyExpensive()...
        L2.getElement().setInnerHTML(html); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote it wrongly while copy-pasting. I am doing what you're saying i.e. processing in scheduleDeferred. And outside this, I have update UI; which is not working. BTW, I am querying gears database in my processing. The query is a bit heavy for SQLite hence it's taking time. Thanks for your response, I'll edit the original question.

Comment: If thats the case, you could check whether the UI update is executed (but is deferred by the browser because of the expensive sqlite calls you have to make) - insert GWT.log() between the call to Scheduler.get()... and L2.setEnabled()...

Comment: I have resolved this other way by speeding up the query (added indexes in SQLite), so it's returning quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into GWT's [IncrementalCommand](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html#incremental) which can help with long running calculations.